# Sum of digits issue

Tags: java, algorithm, sum-of-digits

I'm doing some problems of Project Euler and I've stumbled upon an issue.
I have no idea why this algorithm doesn't work for 2^1000. It works for numbers in the range of 10^1 and 10^8 (Those are the ones I tested), but it should work for every possible range.

2^1000 is 1.07*10^301 by the way. The upper limit of a double lies at more or less 10^308 so the number is still in range.

```
import java.lang.Math;

public class Euler15 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        int count = 0;
        double res = Math.pow(2,1000);

        for(int i = 301; i >= 0; i--){
            if (res == 0){
                break;
            }
            while (res >= Math.pow(10, i)){
                res-= Math.pow(10, i);
                System.out.println(res);
                count++;
            }
        }

    System.out.println(count);
}
}
```

Comment: Because 2^1000 is way to big!

Comment: Probably a rounding issue.

Comment: Just because it's in range of `double` doesn't mean that you get all the digits up until units.

Comment: double only has 15-16 digits of precision no matter how big the number is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

2^1000 is way to big for normal data types. Use BigInteger or strings.

```
import java.math.BigInteger;
```

Take an input as a BigInteger:

```
BigInteger n = BigInteger.valueOf(2);
```

Now power it up to 1000:

```
n = n.pow(1000);
```

Now, convert it into a string using `toString()` and then, add each character to your result, changing it to an `int`. That ought to do it.